# Postman Pre-request script for Token

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, postman, token, postman-pre-request-script

I try to write Pre-script for auto-refresh for token before any request. I know about async, but for first two pm.sendRequest everything is okey, but last pm.sendRequest failed for some reason with error "unauthorised". But Activation token from `jsonResponseActivationToken` is on their place.

```
const newActivationRequest = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: newActivationUrl,
    body: {
    }
};

const activationTokenRequest = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: activationTokenUrl,
    body: {
    }
};

const sessionTokenRequest = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: sessionTokenUrl,
    body: {
    }
};

pm.sendRequest(newActivationRequest, (err, responseNewActivation) => {
    const jsonResponseNewActivation = responseNewActivation.json();
    const statusNewActivation = jsonResponseNewActivation.status;
    
    if(statusNewActivation === 'SUCCESS'){
        pm.sendRequest(activationTokenRequest, (err, responseActivationToken) => {
            const jsonResponseActivationToken = responseActivationToken.json();
            const statusTokenRequest = jsonResponseActivationToken.status;

            if(statusTokenRequest === 'SUCCESS'){
                const newAccessToken = jsonResponseActivationToken.access_token;
                pm.collectionVariables.set('token', newAccessToken);

                pm.sendRequest(sessionTokenRequest, (err, responseSessionToken) => {
                    const jsonResponseSessionToken = responseSessionToken.json();
                    const statusSessionToken = jsonResponseSessionToken.status;

                    console.log('8');

                    if(statusSessionToken === 'SUCCESS'){
                        const newSessionToken = jsonResponseSessionToken.access_token;
                        pm.collectionVariables.set('token', newSessionToken);
                    }

                });
            
            }

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I found the problem: collection variables set only after ALL code in pre-request script is done.

Comment: So, question for now: how to set it and only then call last sendRequest?